# Purchasing a Steam Game in Europe (though I am a US citizen)

Tags: steam, region-lock

Ok, I'm hoping this question doesn't get closed with regards to small locale as I'm trying to cover all of Europe with this one :)

I am a US citizen currently working on an international assignment in Europe, and I am an avid gamer.

Does anybody here know if it is possible to purchase the North American versions of games while in Europe?  I notice that the Steam store recognizes that I am over here and everything shows up priced in Euros.  Does this also mean I'm getting a localized version of the game as well?

If so, any way to circumvent this so that I don't run into any problems when my assignment is complete?

Comment: Not only will the games be localized, but going by conversations with people from Europe, Steam has higher prices on that side of the pond as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can often get around the blocks that they have in place by simply contacting Steam Support (you need to register a separate account at their site) and requesting the American store, but you will then have to pay with an American credit card.  I did this several times when I was in Australia and it takes 1-3 days for them to unlock your account to do so, so it may not be the best option for grabbing that game on sale.

I played the uncensored version of L4D2 while I was in Australia via this method, though I couldn't play multiplayer (I'm not sure if there were any local multiplayer servers in any case)

Comment: If you have a US creditcard, you can just add ?cc=us to the link, like [this](http://store.steampowered.com/?cc=us).

Comment: @ArdaXi I wasn't sure if you could just do that or you had to ask them to enable it.

Comment: I think this is probably the safest route...when in doubt contact support...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As part of the ordering process, you'll still have to declare your actual country of residence. Whatever you enter there should be the version of the game you receive. However, I have never seen any game on Steam that was region-locked, only slightly different versions (to comply with local law, censorship etc.)

The only exception is when the game is illegal in the country you are currently in, as many games are in Germany for example.

Comment: An example of a game which is limited by region is GTA San Andreas - and in fact, most of Rockstar's catalog - which is not sold in some regions even though it's legal there.

Comment: And the fun part is I am in Germany!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can ask a friend from the US to buy a gift copy for you. That usually works fine. (There may be exceptions, but I haven't encoutered one yet.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try routing through a proxy server in America.  That would give steam the appearance that you are in the US.

Comment: Depending on how much you trust the proxy with your credit card details...

Comment: I'd definitely recommend against this. If they find out you run the risk of having your Steam account permanently disabled seeing as it's against the law (fraud).

Comment: @Mechko There are plenty of legit proxies.  It also takes like 30 seconds to apt-get squid.

Answer (score 1):

If you have relatives or someone trusted back in the US, then you might let them login with your account, and buy the game for you.

You can still download and install the game yourself here in Germany or anywhere else, it will be the US version you will play.

Comment: I agree this would be the best answer